# pass touch event to beneath view depends on upper views touch

Tags: android, view, touch, gesture, touch-event

I have layout like following.

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <Button/><Button/>
 </LinearLayout>

 <DisabledGestureView android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
      id="@+android/content_frame" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <ImageView android:layout_width="200dp"
         id="@+android/icon" 
         android:layout_height="200dp">
      </FrameLayout>

 </DisabledGestureView>
</FrameLayout>
```

DisableGestureView is my customView extended from GestureOverlayView. It looks like following..

```
public class DisabledGestureView extends GestureOverlayView {

public DisabledGestureView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private boolean mIsDisable = true;

public void setDisableStatus(boolean status) {
    mIsDisable = status;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    MLog.d("", "overlay touch : " + mIsDisable);
    if (mIsDisable) {
        return false;
    }       
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mIsDisable) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
}
```

If user clicks on imageview(id = icon), i dont want to pass touch event to linearlayout. if user clicks on framelayout(id = content_frame), i want to pass touch event to linearlayout to support onclick of button. Can anybody suggest me how to do this?

Ontouch of image view and frameLayout:

```
 imageview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                disabledGestureView.setDisableStatus(false);


            return false;
        }
    });


    framelayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            disabledGestureView.setDisableStatus(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: In onTouch of imageView i am calling DisabledGestureView.setDisableStatus(false); and in onTouch of framelayout(id = content_frame) i am calling DisabledGestureView.setDisableStatus(true); for allow/diaallow touch event to beneath view of DisabledGestureView. But it makes no use.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass down the touch then return false (not handled) in the `onTouch` if you dont want to pass it down the return true (handled). all you have to do is then find out what view was touched

Comment: @tyczg.., I have already did as you said. I have added touchevent of imageview and framelayout for your reference. But button click not works when i click on exact position over framelayout.

Comment: no you didnt, returning the super method passes down the touch event, so you are always returning false

Comment: welcome 4 your reply.. do you want me to return true instead of returning super.onTouchEvent(ev) at onTouch of DisabledGestureView..?

Comment: if you only want to pass the touch on the framelayout and that is never going to change all you have to do in your `onTouchListener` of your `ImageView` is return true. you dont need your gestureoverlay class

Comment: Here why i am using GestureOverlayView is to draw custom gesture. I need this badly. Touch on imageView should start to draw gesture drawing and touch on Framelayout should pass touch to button click. This what am trying to achieve...